# matlab difficulty importing .xml data from Dexcom blood glucose sensor - help! Not a programmer, just a diabetic who would like to enjoy a burger

Tags: matlab, textscan

My .xml data looks like this`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Patient SerialNumber="SM62169666" IsKeepPrivate="1" IsDataBlinded="0" Id="{D9A334A0-C15E-405A-87FD-E2B3CB172A9C}">
-<MeterReadings>
<Meter Value="166" InternalTime="2014-03-20 20:54:16" DisplayTime="2014-03-20 12:53:33"/>
<Meter Value="176" InternalTime="2014-03-20 21:06:46" DisplayTime="2014-03-20 13:06:03"/>
<Meter Value="86" InternalTime="2014-03-21 03:24:04" DisplayTime="2014-03-20 19:23:22"/>
<Meter Value="56" InternalTime="2014-03-21 10:59:35" DisplayTime="2014-03-21 02:58:52"/>
<Meter Value="249" InternalTime="2014-03-22 01:21:11" DisplayTime="2014-03-21 17:20:29"/>`

and its a large file that I will have to read in blocks. However, I am currently just trying to read in the first line that contains meaningful data - the Meter Value and the DisplayTime.  I thought I should used textscan.  I open the file and try to pull out the data as follows:

```
C = textscan(fid,'<Meter Value="%d " InternalTime="%s %s" DisplayTime="%s %s %*[^\n]',5,'HeaderLines',3)
```

I get C =

```
[0x1 int32]    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}

[0x1 int32]    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}
```

and, it says these cells are empty.  It should be reading 5 lines of data, not just 2. And, these cells should not be empty.  ???  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first input for Textscan is the fileID for the file generated when you use fopen, not just the name of the file.

Try

```
fid = fopen('C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\bgData.xml')
C=textscan(fid,'<Meter Value="%d " InternalTime="%s %s" DisplayTime="%s %s %*[^\n]',5,'HeaderLines',3)
fclose(fid)
```

There are also seems to be some issues with your formatspec itself.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I tried fid first. Output confirms that it is opening and closing the file successfully. I don't know whats up with the formatting.  Its supposed to remove the "<Meter Value="" and all the other titles on the data.  Eventually, I just want the numeric meter value, numeric 'Display Time' date and time in an array.  It was so easy in my mind....

Comment: For more complex pattern matching like yours I'd suggest using      tokens= regexp( str, expression, 'tokens' )